# Error with XPRESS and JAVA

Tags: java

I did a simple program to try Xpress library with java,

I added the related jar files (xprs, xprm, xprb) into my classpath, but I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.dashoptimization.XPRM.mminit()I
>
> at com.dashoptimization.XPRM.mminit(Native Method)
>
> at com.dashoptimization.XPRM.(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.dashoptimization.XPRM.(Unknown Source)
>
> at myPackage.Main.main(Main.java:23)

when excecuting:

```
XPRM mosel = new XPRM();
```

I'm using Netbeans with jdk 1.7 on Windows 7 64bit, I also try it on Windows XP SP3 32 bit with same result.

Thnks for help.

Comment: are you sure it's correctly set on the classpath?

Comment: i think yes, but i'm not 100% sure i set all the things properly.
i copied the .jar and .lib files from ..\xpressmp\lib to ..\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\ext